# E/Buffer Error(15532): Error converting result java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream

Tags: android

My issue is as follows I am developing an app that is reading a JSON object array into a string arraylist which should be used in a list adapter after grabbing the data what seems to be happening is when I try try to set the ListView adapter to the the simple adapter created it blows up with the error in the title namely Error converting result java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream. any help would be appreciated I have attached the class in question below

```
    package com.jbsoft.android;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ActivityGroup;

import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.jbsoft.library.JSONParser;
import com.jbsoft.library.UserFunctions;

public class Policies  extends ActivityGroup{
    protected static LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager;
    ;
    protected static  ArrayList<String> policy_list= new ArrayList<String>();   // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
UserFunctions uf = new UserFunctions();
JSONArray policies = null;




// products JSONArray
JSONArray policylist = null;    
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> policies_List = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 

// url to make request

private static String policiesURL = "http://api.agentpitstop.com/mobile/policies.php?action=status&start=2010-01-01&end=2013-12-31";
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_POLICIES = "policies";
private static final String TAG_FIRST = "firstname";
private static final String TAG_LAST = "lastname";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCERID = "producerid";
private static final String TAG_COMPANY = "company";
private static final String TAG_PLAN = "plan";
private static final String TAG_POLICYID = "policyid";
private static final String TAG_POLICYNUMBER = "policynumber";
private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";
private static final String TAG_SUBMITTED= "submitted";
private static final String TAG_EFFECTIVE= "effective";
private static final String TAG_ADDED= "added";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL= "email"; 
private static final String TAG_PHONE= "phone";
 private static final String TAG_CHANGED= "changed";
private static final String TAG_TERMINATION= "termination";
private static final String TAG_GUID= "guid";
private static final String TAG_CLIENTID= "clientid";
private static final String TAG_POLICYTYPE= "policytype";
private static final String TAG_POLICYPRODUCER= "policyproducer";
private static final String TAG_PRIMARYAGENT= "primaryagent";
    // contacts JSONArray

protected  ListView lv;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.policies_list);
     new LoadPolicies().execute();


 }

     /**
         * Background Async Task to Load agents policies submissions
         * */
        class LoadPolicies extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
             ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> policies_List = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 
            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Policies.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading Submitted Policies");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            /**
             * getting policy JSON
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // Hashmap for ListView

                // getting JSON string from URL

                GlobalVariable apploginurl = ((GlobalVariable)getApplicationContext());
                apploginurl.getState();
                String startdate = apploginurl.getStartDate();
                String enddate = apploginurl.getEndDate();

                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                JSONObject json1 = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(apploginurl.saveurl, params);
                JSONObject json2 = uf.getSubmissions(startdate, enddate);


                // Check your log cat for JSON response  // Hashmap for ListView


                try {
                    policies = json2.getJSONArray(TAG_POLICIES);
                    // looping through All messages
                    for (int i = 0; i < policies.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = policies.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String firstname = c.getString(TAG_FIRST);
                        String last = c.getString(TAG_LAST);
                        String producerid = c.getString(TAG_PRODUCERID);
                        String company = c.getString(TAG_COMPANY);
                        String plan = c.getString(TAG_PLAN);
                        String policyid = c.getString(TAG_POLICYID);
                        String policynumber = c.getString(TAG_POLICYNUMBER);
                        String status = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
                        String submitted = c.getString(TAG_SUBMITTED);
                        String effective = c.getString( TAG_EFFECTIVE);
                        String added = c.getString(TAG_ADDED);
                   //     String changed = c.getString(TAG_CHANGED);
                        String termination = c.getString(TAG_TERMINATION);
                        String guid = c.getString(TAG_GUID);
                        String clientid = c.getString(TAG_CLIENTID);
                        String policytype = c.getString(TAG_POLICYTYPE);
                        String policyproducer = c.getString(TAG_POLICYPRODUCER);
                        String primaryagent = c.getString( TAG_PRIMARYAGENT);
                        String phone = c.getString(TAG_PHONE);
                        String email = c.getString( TAG_EMAIL);
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_FIRST, firstname);
                        map.put(TAG_LAST, last);
                        map.put(TAG_COMPANY,company);
                        map.put(TAG_PRODUCERID, producerid);
                        map.put(TAG_PLAN, plan);
                        map.put(TAG_POLICYID,policyid);
                        map.put(TAG_POLICYNUMBER, policynumber);
                        map.put(TAG_STATUS, status);
                        map.put(TAG_SUBMITTED,submitted);
                        map.put(TAG_EFFECTIVE, effective);
                        map.put(TAG_ADDED, added);
                        map.put(TAG_TERMINATION,termination);
                        map.put(TAG_GUID, guid);
                        map.put(TAG_CLIENTID, clientid);
                        map.put(TAG_POLICYTYPE, policytype);
                        map.put(TAG_PRIMARYAGENT, primaryagent);
                        map.put(TAG_POLICYPRODUCER, policyproducer);
                        map.put(TAG_PHONE, phone);
                        map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);        
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        policies_List.add(map);

                    }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

        }
            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                pDialog.dismiss();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                     ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                             Policies.this, policies_List,
                             R.layout.policies_list_item, new String[] { TAG_FIRST, TAG_LAST,TAG_COMPANY},
                             new int[] {R.id.first,R.id.last, R.id.company});


                         lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                         lv.getAdapter();
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                 @Override
                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                          int position, long id) {

                         Intent in = new Intent(view.getContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);

                         //Activity1 parentActivity = (Activity1)getParent();
                         replaceContentView("policies_list_item_detail", in);

                      // getting values from selected ListItem
                      String first = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.first)).getText().toString();
                      String last = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.last)).getText().toString();
                      String company = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.company)).getText().toString();
                      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                        String plan = policies_List.get(position).get(TAG_PLAN);
                      // Starting new intent

                      in.putExtra(TAG_FIRST, first);
                      in.putExtra(TAG_LAST, last);
                      in.putExtra(TAG_COMPANY, company);
                      in.putExtra(TAG_PLAN, policies_List.get(position).get(TAG_PLAN));
                      in.putExtra(TAG_SUBMITTED, policies_List.get(position).get(TAG_SUBMITTED));
                      in.putExtra(TAG_STATUS, policies_List.get(position).get(TAG_STATUS));
                      in.putExtra(TAG_EFFECTIVE, policies_List.get(position).get(TAG_EFFECTIVE));
                      in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE, policies_List.get(position).get(TAG_PHONE));
                      in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, policies_List.get(position).get(TAG_EMAIL));

                      startActivity(in);
                  }
              });



                    }});
                }
public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {
View view =       getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)) .getDecorView(); setContentView(view);
```

}
           }

Here's my Log.....

```
                08-15 19:06:50.166: W/ActivityThread(15532): Application com.jbsoft.android is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
            08-15 19:06:50.170: I/System.out(15532): Sending WAIT chunk
            08-15 19:06:50.182: I/dalvikvm(15532): Debugger is active
            08-15 19:06:50.369: I/System.out(15532): Debugger has connected
            08-15 19:06:50.369: I/System.out(15532): waiting for debugger to settle...
            08-15 19:06:50.569: I/System.out(15532): waiting for debugger to settle...
            08-15 19:06:50.772: I/System.out(15532): waiting for debugger to settle...
            08-15 19:06:50.971: I/System.out(15532): waiting for debugger to settle...
            08-15 19:06:51.186: I/System.out(15532): waiting for debugger to settle...
            08-15 19:06:51.389: I/System.out(15532): waiting for debugger to settle...
            08-15 19:06:51.588: I/System.out(15532): waiting for debugger to settle...
            08-15 19:06:51.791: I/System.out(15532): debugger has settled (1353)
            08-15 19:06:52.408: I/global(15532): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
            08-15 19:06:52.588: D/dalvikvm(15532): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 964 objects / 90272 bytes in 87ms
            08-15 19:06:52.686: I/System.out(15532): Could not parse java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'null' as integer
            08-15 19:06:52.866: W/ResourceType(15532): Skipping entry 0x7f05000a in package table 0 because it is not complex!
            08-15 19:06:52.869: W/ResourceType(15532): Skipping entry 0x7f05000a in package table 0 because it is not complex!
            08-15 19:06:52.877: W/ResourceType(15532): Skipping entry 0x7f05000a in package table 0 because it is not complex!
            08-15 19:06:52.877: W/ResourceType(15532): Skipping entry 0x7f05000a in package table 0 because it is not complex!
            08-15 19:06:52.881: W/ResourceType(15532): Skipping entry 0x7f05000a in package table 0 because it is not complex!
            08-15 19:06:53.158: D/skia(15532): purging 6K from font cache [1 entries]
            08-15 19:06:53.158: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): stored typeface in slot 0
            08-15 19:06:53.170: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): SKIA_FONT fontfile: /data/data/com.android.settings/app_fonts/default/DroidSans.ttf
            08-15 19:06:53.182: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): SKIA_FONT fontfile: /data/data/com.android.settings/app_fonts/default/DroidSans.ttf
            08-15 19:06:53.182: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Sans, style = 0, uniqueID = 13
            08-15 19:06:53.182: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): SKIA_FONT fontfile: /data/data/com.android.settings/app_fonts/default/DroidSans-Bold.ttf
            08-15 19:06:53.213: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): SKIA_FONT fontfile: /data/data/com.android.settings/app_fonts/default/DroidSans-Bold.ttf
            08-15 19:06:53.213: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Sans, style = 1, uniqueID = 14
            08-15 19:06:53.260: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Serif, style = 0, uniqueID = 15
            08-15 19:06:53.276: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Serif, style = 1, uniqueID = 16
            08-15 19:06:53.291: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Serif, style = 2, uniqueID = 17
            08-15 19:06:53.307: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Serif, style = 3, uniqueID = 18
            08-15 19:06:53.319: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Sans Mono, style = 0, uniqueID = 19
            08-15 19:06:53.323: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Sans Arabic, style = 0, uniqueID = 20
            08-15 19:06:53.330: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Sans Hebrew, style = 0, uniqueID = 21
            08-15 19:06:53.366: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Sans Thai, style = 0, uniqueID = 22
            08-15 19:06:53.405: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Sans, style = 0, uniqueID = 23
            08-15 19:06:53.491: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Sans Fallback, style = 0, uniqueID = 24
            08-15 19:06:53.491: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): load_system_fonts(), oldSansUID = 1, newSansUID = 13
            08-15 19:06:53.491: D/SKIA_FONT(15532): load_system_fonts(), oldSansBoldUID = 2, newSansBoldUID = 14
            08-15 19:06:58.151: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(15532): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
            08-15 19:07:11.537: D/dalvikvm(15532): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1616 objects / 94344 bytes in 34ms
            08-15 19:07:19.143: I/System.out(15532): executing request http://<domain>/mobile/authenticate.php?action=login&username=<user>&password=<password>
            08-15 19:07:21.284: D/dalvikvm(15532): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2134 objects / 118480 bytes in 45ms
            08-15 19:07:24.752: I/System.out(15532): executing request http://<domain>/mobile/authenticate.php?action=login&username=<user>&password=<password>
            08-15 19:07:26.635: E/JSON(15532): {"success":true,"message":"Successfully logged in.","uid":"3401"}
            08-15 19:07:27.518: D/dalvikvm(15532): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1590 objects / 80792 bytes in 36ms
            08-15 19:07:30.940: E/Buffer Error(15532): Error converting result java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.
            08-15 19:07:32.299: I/System.out(15532): executing request http://<domain>/mobile/policies.php?action=status&start=2010-01-01&end=2013-12-31
            08-15 19:07:32.405: I/System.out(15532): executing request http://<domain>/mobile/policies.php?action=status&start=2010-01-01&end=2013-12-31
            08-15 19:07:32.592: D/dalvikvm(15532): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2396 objects / 115488 bytes in 37ms
            08-15 19:07:33.252: D/dalvikvm(15532): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 137 objects / 188984 bytes in 42ms
            08-15 19:07:34.315: I/JSON(15532): {"success":true,"policies":[{"firstname":"test","lastname":"test","producerid":"10115","company":"Anthem Blue Cross","plan":"Anthem PPO 2013","policyid":"50864","policynumber":"12345678","status":"Active","submitted":"Jul 20 2013 12:00:00:000AM","effective":"Aug  1 2013 12:00:00:000AM","added":"Sep 25 2012 04:19:45:163PM","changed":"Jul 19 2013 10:56:36:633AM","termination":"","guid":"38286","email":"ernesto@vanbergins.com","phone":"9253030957","birthday":"","address":"","city":"","state":"","zip":"","bflagphone":"1","clientid":"38286","policytype":"Medicare Advantage","policyproducer":"Test, Guest","primaryagent":"Test, Guest"},{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","producerid":"10115","company":"AARP","plan":"AARP Medicare RX Preffered","policyid":"36291","policynumber":"PENDING","status":"Cancelled","submitted":"May 30 2012 11:44:31:927AM","effective":"Jul  1 2012 11:44:35:277AM","added":"Sep 15 2011 11:44:41:640AM","changed":"May 30 2012 09:50:32:770AM","termination":"","guid":"33601","email":"","phone":"9256345702","birthday":"","address":"","city":"","state":"","zip":"","bflagphone":"1","clientid":"33601","policytype":"Medicare Part D","policyproducer":"Test, Guest","primaryagent":"Test, Guest"},{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","producerid":"10115","company":"Anthem Blue Cross","plan":"Plan F","policyid":"36289","policynumber":"012A3456","status":"Active","submitted":"May 30 2012 11:43:12:450AM","effective":"Jul  1 2012 11:43:17:340AM","added":"Sep 15 2011 11:43:30:203AM","changed":"May 30 2012 09:57:08:943AM","termination":"","guid":"33601","email":"","phone":"9256345702","birthday":"","address":"","city":"","state":"","zip":"","bflagphone":"1","clientid":"33601","policytype":"Medicare Supplement","policyproducer":"Test, Guest","primaryagent":"Test, Guest"},{"firstname":"test","lastname":"test","producerid":"10115","company":"Z NIU * WellCare","plan":"Z NIU * WellCare Sonata","policyid":"46700","policynumber":"CANCELLED","status":"Cancelled","submitted":"May 19 2012 12:00:00:000AM","effective":"Jul  1 2012 12:00:00:000AM","added":"Feb  6 2012 08:24:17:977PM","changed":"Jul 19 2013 10:56:47:497AM","termination":"Jan  1 1990 12:00:00:000AM","guid":"38286","email":"ernesto@vanbergins.com","phone":"9253030957","birthday":"","address":"","city":"","state":"","zip":"","bflagphone":"1","clientid":"38286","policytype":"Medicare Advantage","policyproducer":"Test, Guest","primaryagent":"Test, Guest"},{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","producerid":"10115","company":"Humana","plan":"Humana Walmart-Preferred RX","policyid":"34417","policynumber":"PENDING","status":"Pending","submitted":"Apr 15 2011 11:36:32:680AM","effective":"May  1 2011 11:36:32:683AM","added":"Apr 15 2011 11:36:46:153AM","changed":"Apr 15 2011 11:37:11:950AM","termination":"Apr 15 2011 11:37:09:227AM","guid":"33602","email":"ernesto@agentpitstop.com","phone":"9254186012","birthday":"","address":"","city":"","state":"","zip":"","bflagphone":"1","clientid":"33602","policytype":"Medicare Part D","policyproducer":"Test, Guest","primaryagent":"Test, Guest"},{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","producerid":"10115","company":"Anthem Blue Cross","plan":"Anthem","policyid":"34413","policynumber":"321A98765","status":"Active","submitted":"Apr 15 2011 11:32:42:540AM","effective":"May  1 2011 11:32:42:543AM","added":"Apr 15 2011 11:33:18:183AM","changed":"Apr 15 2011 11:37:22:860AM","termination":"Apr 15 2011 11:37:20:990AM","guid":"33602","email":"ernesto@agentpitstop.com","phone":"9254186012","birthday":"","address":"","city":"","state":"","zip":"","bflagphone":"1","clientid":"33602","policytype":"Medicare Advantage","policyproducer":"Test, Guest","primaryagent":"Test, Guest"}]}
            08-15 19:07:34.319: E/JSON(15532): {"success":true,"policies":[{"firstname":"test","lastname":"test","producerid":"10115","company":"Anthem Blue Cross","plan":"Anthem PPO 2013","policyid":"50864","policynumber":"12345678","status":"Active","submitted":"Jul 20 2013 12:00:00:000AM","effective":"Aug  1 2013 12:00:00:000AM","added":"Sep 25 2012 04:19:45:163PM","changed":"Jul 19 2013 10:56:36:633AM","termination":"","guid":"38286","email":"ernesto@vanbergins.com","phone":"9253030957","birthday":"","address":"","city":"","state":"","zip":"","bflagphone":"1","clientid":"38286","policytype":"Medicare Advantage","policyproducer":"Test, Guest","primaryagent":"Test, Guest"},{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","producerid":"10115","company":"AARP","plan":"AARP Medicare RX Preffered","policyid":"36291","policynumber":"PENDING","status":"Cancelled","submitted":"May 30 2012 11:44:31:927AM","effective":"Jul  1 2012 11:44:35:277AM","added":"Sep 15 2011 11:44:41:640AM","changed":"May 30 2012 09:50:32:770AM","termination":"","guid":"33601","email":"","phone":"9256345702","birthday":"","address":"","city":"","state":"","zip":"","bflagphone":"1","clientid":"33601","policytype":"Medicare Part D","policyproducer":"Test, Guest","primaryagent":"Test, Guest"},{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","producerid":"10115","company":"Anthem Blue Cross","plan":"Plan F","policyid":"36289","policynumber":"012A3456","status":"Active","submitted":"May 30 2012 11:43:12:450AM","effective":"Jul  1 2012 11:43:17:340AM","added":"Sep 15 2011 11:43:30:203AM","changed":"May 30 2012 09:57:08:943AM","termination":"","guid":"33601","email":"","phone":"9256345702","birthday":"","address":"","city":"","state":"","zip":"","bflagphone":"1","clientid":"33601","policytype":"Medicare Supplement","policyproducer":"Test, Guest","primaryagent":"Test, Guest"},{"firstname":"test","lastname":"test","producerid":"10115","company":"Z NIU * WellCare","plan":"Z NIU * WellCare Sonata","policyid":"46700","policynumber":"CANCELLED","status":"Cancelled","submitted":"May 19 2012 12:00:00:000AM","effective":"Jul  1 2012 12:00:00:000AM","added":"Feb  6 2012 08:24:17:977PM","changed":"Jul 19 2013 10:56:47:497AM","termination":"Jan  1 1990 12:00:00:000AM","guid":"38286","email":"ernesto@vanbergins.com","phone":"9253030957","birthday":"","address":"","city":"","state":"","zip":"","bflagphone":"1","clientid":"38286","policytype":"Medicare Advantage","policyproducer":"Test, Guest","primaryagent":"Test, Guest"},{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","producerid":"10115","company":"Humana","plan":"Humana Walmart-Preferred RX","policyid":"34417","policynumber":"PENDING","status":"Pending","submitted":"Apr 15 2011 11:36:32:680AM","effective":"May  1 2011 11:36:32:683AM","added":"Apr 15 2011 11:36:46:153AM","changed":"Apr 15 2011 11:37:11:950AM","termination":"Apr 15 2011 11:37:09:227AM","guid":"33602","email":"ernesto@agentpitstop.com","phone":"9254186012","birthday":"","address":"","city":"","state":"","zip":"","bflagphone":"1","clientid":"33602","policytype":"Medicare Part D","policyproducer":"Test, Guest","primaryagent":"Test, Guest"},{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","producerid":"10115","company":"Anthem Blue Cross","plan":"Anthem","policyid":"34413","policynumber":"321A98765","status":"Active","submitted":"Apr 15 2011 11:32:42:540AM","effective":"May  1 2011 11:32:42:543AM","added":"Apr 15 2011 11:33:18:183AM","changed":"Apr 15 2011 11:37:22:860AM","termination":"Apr 15 2011 11:37:20:990AM","guid":"33602","email":"ernesto@agentpitstop.com","phone":"9254186012","birthday":"","address":"","city":"","state":"","zip":"","bflagphone":"1","clientid":"33602","policytype":"Medicare Advantage","policyproducer":"Test, Guest","primaryagent":"Test, Guest"}]}
            **08-15 19:07:34.565: E/Buffer Error(15532): Error converting result java.io.IOException: Attempted read on closed stream.**
            08-15 19:07:43.698: D/dalvikvm(15532): threadid=9: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1 s=Y)
            08-15 19:07:46.010: D/dalvikvm(15532): threadid=9: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1 s=Y)
            08-15 19:08:07.498: D/PhoneWindow(15532): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@47c7ddc8 has no id.
```

Comment: Can you provide a call stack from logcat?

Comment: I have attached the log above